# How to reduce Qtime (query time) in Solr

Tags: apache, search, solr

I need to reduce qtime in Solr from 24ms to 10ms. I have tried with the following parameters:

```
responseHeader: {
  status: 0,
  QTime: 24,
  params: {
    json.wrf: "jQuery111205813984868582338_1454571708911",
    sort: "id desc",
    indent: "on",
    hl.simple.pre: "<b>",
    hl.fl: "title keywords model_name",
    wt: "json",
    hl: "true",
    rows: "100",
    hl.highlightMultiTerm: "true",
    hl.snippets: "1",
    start: "0",
    q: "{!q.op=AND df=title}pl~1",
    _: "1454571708913",
    hl.simple.post: "</b>",
    qt: "spellchecker",
    hl.usePhraseHighlighter: "true"
    }
  }
```

Solr URL:

```
 http://www.example.com:8983/solr/mycoll/select?q={!q.op=AND%20df=title}pl~1&indent=on&sort=id%20desc&qt=spellchecker&wt=json&hl=true&hl.fl=title+keywords+model_name&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.snippets=1&start=0&rows=100&json.wrf=jQuery111205813984868582338_1454571708911&_=1454571708913
```

schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Please see these reference links:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2218

Comment: The query time will depend on the cachability of your query and how you've configured the caches. Doing a fuzzy search is probably going to be bad as well. Experiment with different query times, use a good warming strategy (to get the relevant entries into the cache) and make sure the index files fit into available memory.

Comment: 2ms is quite low for a web service and it seems strange that you need rows=100 together with such snappy results. Why 2ms? If it is because you need to support 500 requests/second then you should remember that Solr handles parallel requests just fine.

Comment: is there way that we can pass  in parameters which would result reduction qtime

Comment: I believe there is no such magic. As mentioned before, make sure you have proper caching and a good index design with proper capacity for your load. You haven't mentioned anything about your index size and qps.